# Bootstrap слайдер

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Создал слайдер на бутстрапе, но есть такой минус, когда курсор находится в контейнере, то слайдер перестает автоматически менять изображения, их можно менять только в ручную. Как это исправить?

```
<div id="myimgslide" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myimgslide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myimgslide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myimgslide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myimgslide" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" >

    <div class="item ">
        <img src="~/Content/chain2.jpg" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Заголовок 1 слайда</h1>
            @*<p>Текст (описание) 1 слайда...</p>*@
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item active">
        <img src="~/Content/chain2.jpg" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Заголовок 2 слайда</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item ">
        <img src="~/Content/chain2.jpg" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Заголовок 3 слайда</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item ">
        <img src="~/Content/chain2.jpg" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Заголовок 3 слайда</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myimgslide" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myimgslide" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: false
});
```